# how to find the date difference in hours between two records with nearest datetime value and it must be compared in same group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datediff

How to find the date difference in hours between two records with nearest datetime value and it must be compared in same group?

Sample Data as follows:

```
Select * from tblGroup
```

```
Group      FinishedDatetime
1          03-01-2009 00:00
1          13-01-2009 22:00
1          08-01-2009 03:00
2          01-01-2009 10:00
2          13-01-2009 20:00
2          10:01-2009 10:00
3          27-10-2008 00:00
3          29-10-2008 00:00
```

Expected Output :

```
Group      FinishedDatetime     Hours
1          03-01-2009 00:00     123 
1          13-01-2009 22:00     139
1          08-01-2009 03:00     117
2          01-01-2009 10:00     216
2          13-01-2009 20:00     82
2          10:01-2009 10:00     82
3          27-10-2008 00:00     48
3          29-10-2008 00:00     48
```

Comment: mysql or sqlserver you tagged with both ? Also what would be your expected output from the given dataset ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select t1.[Group], DATEDIFF(HOUR, z.FinishedDatetime, t1.FinishedDatetime)
FROM tblGroup t1
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 *
            FROM tblGroup t2 
            WHERE t2.[Group] = t1.[Group] AND t2.FinishedDatetime<t1.FinishedDatetime
            ORDER BY FinishedDatetime DESC)z
```

Comment: after executing your query I got error as follows : " The Multipart Identifier t2.FinishedDatetime could not be bound "

Comment: @Kapil. I change my query. Please Try again.